# xmlagg in sql query not producing complete output

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing one issue while using XMLAgg in my seletc query.
I am not getting complete o/p while executing the below query:

```
select XMLELEMENT
("SAPC", XMLAgg 
(XMLELEMENT
("AT",
XMLATTRIBUTES(dn.dn_num as MSISDN, ict.TEXT01 as IMEI, at1.TAC as TAC))))
from (select TAC,city from AT_Test at where city in 
(select cc.CCCITY from 
ccontact_all cc, contract_all ca where
cc.customer_id = ca.customer_id and
trunc(CO_INSTALLED) >= '30-MAY-2014') ) at1, 
ccontact_all cc, contract_all ca, directory_number dn, contr_services_cap csc,
INFO_CONTR_TEXT ict where
cc.customer_id = ca.customer_id and
ca.co_id = csc.co_id and
at1.city = cc.CCCITY and
csc.dn_id = dn.dn_id and
ict.co_id = ca.co_id and
trunc(CO_INSTALLED) >= '30-MAY-2014';
```

I am getting o/p like

```
 <SAPC><AT MSISDN="213471000153" IMEI="123456789012" TAC="16003"></AT><AT MSISDN=
```

Output should be like

```
<SAPC>
<AT MSISDN="213471000154" IMEI="123456789012" TAC="16003"></AT>
<AT MSISDN=MSISDN="213471000155" IMEI="123456789014" TAC="16002"></AT>
<AT MSISDN="213471000156" IMEI="123456789013" TAC="16003"></AT>
</SAPC>
```

Pls help.

Thanks!!
HK Mishra

Answer (score 1):

what tool do you use? My guess is that your tool is trancating your output because you getting exactly 80 characters. And my guess is that your tool is SQL*Plus.

```
set linesize 2000
```

will help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Reply. But i am using below query with some change i.e. i used 'rtrim' as well with the set linesize command but not getting the proper output.

```
select rtrim(XMLELEMENT
("AT", 
XMLAgg
(XMLELEMENT
("SAPC",
XMLATTRIBUTES(dn.dn_num as MSISDN, ict.TEXT01 as IMEI, at1.TAC as TAC)))))
from (select TAC,city from AT_Test at where city in 
(select cc.CCCITY from 
ccontact_all cc, contract_all ca where
cc.customer_id = ca.customer_id and
((to_date(co_installed,'SSSSS') between
to_date(36000,'SSSSS') and to_date(43200,'SSSSS')) or (to_date(CCMODDATE,'SSSSS') between
to_date(36000,'SSSSS') and to_date(43200,'SSSSS')) or (to_date(CO_MODDATE,'SSSSS') between
to_date(36000,'SSSSS') and to_date(43200,'SSSSS'))))) at1, 
ccontact_all cc, contract_all ca, directory_number dn, contr_services_cap csc,
INFO_CONTR_TEXT ict where
cc.customer_id = ca.customer_id and
ca.co_id = csc.co_id and
at1.city = cc.CCCITY and
csc.dn_id = dn.dn_id and
ict.co_id = ca.co_id and
ca.ch_status = 'a' and
((to_date(co_installed,'SSSSS') between
to_date(36000,'SSSSS') and to_date(43200,'SSSSS')) or (to_date(CCMODDATE,'SSSSS') between
to_date(36000,'SSSSS') and to_date(43200,'SSSSS')) or (to_date(CO_MODDATE,'SSSSS') between
to_date(36000,'SSSSS') and to_date(43200,'SSSSS')));
```

I am getting output like:

```
RTRIM(XMLELEMENT("AT",XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("SAPC",XMLATTRIBUTES(DN.DN_NUMASMSISDN,ICT.TEXT01ASIMEI,AT1.TACASTAC)))))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<AT><SAPC MSISDN="213470000095" IMEI="869763011575795" TAC="16001"></SAPC><SAPC MSISDN="213470000096" IMEI="869763011581041" TAC="16001"></SAPC><SAPC MSISDN="213470000098" IMEI="869763011578302" TAC="16001"></SAPC></AT>
```